# Error loading my rqt plugin from rqt_gui

Tags: qt, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
I have written a quick rqt plugin, starting with the roscreate-qt-pkg command to create a package and then following the rqt tutorials.
When trying to load the plugin in rqt_gui, I get the following error:

```
"Failed to load nodelet [control_centre/MyPlugin_1] of type [control_centre/MyPlugin]: Failed to load library /home/pioneer/ros_workspace/control_centre/lib/libcontrol_centre.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_REGISTER_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Cannot load library: No manifest in /home/pioneer/ros_workspace/control_centre/lib/libcontrol_centre.so: control_centre__MyPlugin"
```

I am using ROS fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04.

My manifest.xml is the following:

```
<package>
...
<rosdep name="qt4"/>
<depend package="qt_build"/>
<depend package="roscpp"/>
<depend package="rqt_gui"/>
<depend package="rqt_gui_cpp"/>
<rosbuild2>
   <depend package="qt_build"/>
   <depend package="roscpp"/>
   <depend package="rqt_gui"/>
   <depend package="rqt_gui_cpp"/>
</rosbuild2>
<export>
<rqt_gui plugin="${prefix}/plugin.xml" />
</export>
</package>
```

My plugin.xml is the following:

```
<library path="lib/libcontrol_centre">
  <class name="control_centre/MyPlugin" type="control_centre::MyPlugin" base_class_type="rqt_gui_cpp::Plugin">
    <description>
      Controls for toggling various rescueneer robot features.
    </description>
    <qtgui>
      <label>Rescueneer Control Centre</label>
      <icon type="theme">system-help</icon>
      <statustip>..</statustip>
    </qtgui>
  </class>
</library>
```

My CMakeLists.txt is the following:

```
##############################################################################
# Rosbuild2
##############################################################################

if(ROSBUILD)
  include(rosbuild.cmake OPTIONAL)
  return()
endif()

##############################################################################
# CMake
##############################################################################

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
##############################################################################
# Ros Initialisation
##############################################################################

include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)
rosbuild_init()

#set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
#set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

#include_directories( ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/control_centre )

# Set the build type.  Options are:
#  Coverage       : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization, w/ code-coverage
#  Debug          : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization
#  Release        : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  RelWithDebInfo : w/ debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  MinSizeRel     : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization, stripped binaries
#set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE Debug)

##############################################################################
# Qt Environment
##############################################################################

rosbuild_include(qt_build qt-ros)
rosbuild_prepare_qt4(QtCore QtGui) # Add the appropriate components to the component list here

##############################################################################
# Sections
##############################################################################

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

file(GLOB QT_FORMS RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ui/*.ui)
file(GLOB QT_RESOURCES RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} resources/*.qrc)
file(GLOB_RECURSE QT_MOC RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FOLLOW_SYMLINKS include/control_centre/*.hpp)

QT4_ADD_RESOURCES(QT_RESOURCES_CPP ${QT_RESOURCES})
QT4_WRAP_UI(QT_FORMS_HPP ${QT_FORMS})
QT4_WRAP_CPP(QT_MOC_HPP ${QT_MOC})

##############################################################################
# Sources
##############################################################################

file(GLOB_RECURSE QT_SOURCES RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FOLLOW_SYMLINKS src/*.cpp)

##############################################################################
# Binaries
##############################################################################

rosbuild_add_library(control_centre ${QT_SOURCES} ${QT_RESOURCES_CPP} ${QT_FORMS_HPP} ${QT_MOC_HPP})
rosbuild_add_executable(control_centre ${QT_SOURCES} ${QT_RESOURCES_CPP} ${QT_FORMS_HPP} ${QT_MOC_HPP})
target_link_libraries(control_centre ${QT_LIBRARIES})
```

And finally, my source file has the following declaration at the bottom:

```
PLUGINLIB_DECLARE_CLASS(control_centre, MyPlugin, control_centre::MyPlugin, rqt_gui_cpp::Plugin)
```

I have also compared my code to that of rqt_image_view and I can't find the difference.
The code compiles and I can run it as a stand-alone application, but I can't seem to open it in rqt_gui. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/88931/error-loading-my-rqt-plugin-from-rqt_gui/) by [Valts](https://answers.ros.org/users/7561/valts/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2013-10-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does the solution in [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/12293/error-while-running-nodelet-cannot-load-library-undefined-symbol/) help?

Besides that, `rqt` wasn't yet officially introduced in ROS fuerte and therefore you may face more problems there. Using newer ROS distro (now 2 or 3 newer generations, Hydro and Indigo, are commonly used) is recommended.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2014-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0